# Difference between sufficient and non sufficient statistics

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference

I have a few questions here.

1. Could someone please give me (in plain English, avoiding as much statistical jargon as possible and resorting to examples *one might understand with a only a basic knowledge of statistics and/or mathematics* whenever possible) an example of a non sufficient statistic, and go on to explain **why** it isn't sufficient?
2. When we say "sufficient," what does that **mean?** Sufficient for... what exactly? Why is it so important?
3. What **makes** a sufficient statistic sufficient?

Comment: Hello and welcome to math.stackexhange. This is a concept from advanced  mathematical statistics. It's possible to explain what it means in words, but then you won't be able to do much work with this. So (a) tell us why you want to know this and (b) what is your prior background. Specifically do you what a random variable is? Do you know what a probability mass function is? Do you know what a likelihood function is?

Comment: Hello! I'm currently getting my masters in economics and am studying for my final in advanced statistics. I understand the gist of it, but very little of the topics are explained using simple language (it's very theoretical and I'm more of an applied maths person). For example, the definition we've been given of a sufficient statistics is that "T is sufficient for theta if the conditional distribution of X given T does not involve theta." So I'm wondering what "does not involve" mean and why that's important, and also simply looking for a clearer definition. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

I will provide an intuitive explanation. As Hans Engler comments, if you want to use sufficient statistics, you will eventually have to get get comfortable with the formal definition. But let me do my best to explain sufficiency, as you ask, with minimal jargon.

The core goal of statistical estimation is to gain information about a (usually large) **population** from a much smaller **sample**. Specifically, we may want to estimate certain **parameters** of the population, like the mean (average) or variance. In statistical theory, a sample is given by a bunch of random variables $X_1,\ldots,X_n$, each random variable describing one randomly chosen individual from the population.

A sufficient statistic $U$ is, informally, a *lossless compression* of your sample data. (Or at least, it loses no information for purposes of estimating the parameter of interest.) Say I have two statisticians A and B. To A I give the entire sample $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ and to B I give just our sufficient statistic $U$ and tell him how $U$ was computed. You would imagine that $A$ would be able to make much better predictions of the population parameters since he has the entire dataset, but in fact since $U$ is sufficient both A and B can make equally accurate predictions. In some sense, $U$ represents the entire sample $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ boiled down to one number. (It is important to note that sometimes you need more than one sufficient statistic, but often one will suffice.)

So to directly answer your first question directly, what makes a sufficient statistic sufficient, intuitively, is that having the sufficient statistic is *just as good* as having the whole sample for purposes of estimation of the parameters you care about.

It is important to note that sufficiency is always **for** a particular parameter. If I'm trying to estimate the population mean $\mu$ and you're trying to estimate the population variance $\sigma^2$, we'll need different sufficient statistics.

As a concrete example, consider a population of individuals whose income can be modelled by an exponential distribution with mean $\mu$. (If this means nothing to you, just know the average income is $\mu$.) We then take a sample $X_1,\ldots,X_n$. What would not be a sufficient statistic is $X_1$, just the first element of our sample. This is because if you only know $X_1$, you lose all of the valuable information contained in the rest of the sample. However, the sample mean

$$
\bar{X} = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n X_i}{n}
$$

is sufficient. If you give statistician A all the sample data and B $\bar{X}$, they can make equally accurate predictions (point estimates) of $\mu$.

Comment: Thank you so much! That's very helpful. 

So a follow-up question would be...in my notes, I have that the sum of every Xi is sufficient for an exponential distribution. Could you provide some intuition as to why that is? I understand why the average is helpful, but have trouble understanding why the sum is sufficient.
  
And, one last question: What is an ancillary statistic, precisely? How is ancillary different from sufficient, and why are ancillary statistics important?

Comment: To the first question, remember that a statistic is sufficient if it “contains all the information about the sample”. The sum and the average contain the same information: if I tell you the sum, you can compute the average by dividing by $n$ and I can compute the sum by multiplying the average by $n$. In general, any “one-to-one” transformation of a sufficient statistic is still sufficient since a one-to-one transformation can be inverted.

Comment: Also it is an import misconception that a sufficient statistic need be an estimator of the parameter it is sufficient for: it need not. The sum and the average both sufficient for the mean of an exponential distribution, though only one of these is an unbiased consistent estimator

Comment: Okay, cool. That makes sense. In my notes as I have it, the average is sufficient for a normal distribution, and the sum is sufficient for an exponential (to give just two examples). However, would the average **also** be sufficient for an exponential, or the sum for a normal? And is n always assumed to be known?

Comment: Yes absolutely. Also, $n$ is assumed known.

Comment: Okay cool! Thank you very much!

Comment: @eepperly16 I have a question if you would be kind enough to answer: When you say,

" is that having the sufficient statistic is just as good as having the whole sample for purposes of estimation of the parameters you care about."

Does estimation always refer to maximium liklihood estimation?

Comment: @Mark I'm not a mathematical statistician, and as with all areas of math one is prone to mistakes if one does not understand the subtler points of a theorem. My understanding is that from a sufficient statistic, one can always construct the minimum variance unbiased estimator. See [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lehmann%E2%80%93Scheff%C3%A9_theorem). I may be wrong and there may be cases in which this fails to be true. So the answer to your question is "no": a MVUE will not necessarily be the MLE.

Comment: Thank you very much. Can you then explain the logic behind the statement of "...having the sufficient statistic is just as good as having the whole sample for purposes of estimation..." ? Is it purely just an intuitive thing, or is there something concrete behind this statement about estimation?

Comment: @Mark In principle, any function $f(X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_n)$ can be considered an estimate of any sample parameter. What we usually care about are _good_ estimates. What "good" _means_ is very context dependent. If we take good to mean in the minimum variance unbiased sense, then sufficient statistics contains all the information you need: if $U$ is a sufficient statistic, there is _some_ function of $U$ such that $f(U)$ is the minimum variance unbiased estimator for your parameter. That's fairly concrete. The _best_ estimator in the MVUE sense dependents only on a sufficient statistic

Comment: The deeper reason is that, by definition of sufficiency, if I tell you the value of the sufficient statistic, the probability distributions of all of your sample data is independent of your parameter of interest. So in this sense the rest of your sample data is worthless once you have a sufficient statistic, because its distribution contains no additional information about the parameter than just knowing the sufficient statistic does.

Comment: @eepperly16 Thank you once again, I think I fully understand the intuition now. One last thing: If the definition is

P(x | f, theta) does not depend on theta, does this IMPLY that

P(theta | f, x) = P(theta | f)

So that when evaluating the probability of theta, we can discard x after having seen f?

Answer (score 0):

Well going through your question and comment all I can say about sufficient statistics in simpler terms is that Sufficient statistics is that Statistics which contains the full information about the parameter say theta.

Suppose in Normal distribution the sample mean is the sufficient statistics for the parameter meuw which is the population mean. So when your doing an practical experiment and you need the information about meuw, the population mean, you just need to know the sample mean which will give you all the information you need and you don't have to go through the whole data.

Also the if you think intuitively about the definition you've told in the comment section you'll realise that since T has all the information about theta, the conditional distribution can't give you any more data about theta.

And so you may have now got that Insufficient or Non Sufficient statistics are those which doesn't contain all the information about the parameter.

I hope this helps you in clearing your concept. I've tried to put it in as simple terms as it could get.